# Setting environment variable in Ubuntu 14.04 for OpenFOAM

Tags: environment-variables

[image]

Could you please tell me how should I set an environment variable as mentioned here?

[OpenFOAM wiki](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Extend-bazaar/solvers/combustion/flameletFoam#OpenFOAM_Source)

Set an environment variable to the flameletFoam "src"-folder:

```
export LIB_FLAMELET_SRC=$HOME/($YOUR_PATH)/flameletFoam/src
```

What should I do?

Comment: Just copy-paste that line in the terminal you are going to use to launch the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the previous steps as in the instructions, execute:

```
export LIB_FLAMELET_SRC=$HOME/OpenFOAM/flamletFoam/flameletFoam/src
```

This `($YOUR_PATH)` seems like an artifact from an old version.